# How to call a derived class from Dictionary with EqualComparer

Tags: c#, dictionary, inheritance

I have following class ObservableDictionary created, but got a compiler complain about the constructor call of the base class.

```
base(comparer)
```

Here are a the basic class code..

```
                    
    public class ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
    {
        public ObservableDictionary(IEqualityComparer<TValue> comparer) : base(comparer) {
            
        }

        public new TValue this[TKey key]
        {
            get => base[key];
            set
            {
                if (!ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    base.Add(key, value);

                }

                if (!EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(base[key], value))
                {
                    base[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class CarDiffRank : EqualityComparer<Car> 
    {
        public override bool Equals(Car c1, Car c2)
        {
            return (c1.rank == c2.rank);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode(Car c)
        {
            int hCode = c.rank;
            return hCode.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

I was expecting to trigger the events only on changes in the objects

Comment: what errror message?

Comment: The comparer must be of type `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` and not `TValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparator must be of type TKey not TValue see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-collections-generic-dictionary-2-ctor(system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-0)))